# Reading and writing NSMutableDictionary to a plist file

Tags: ios, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to save `NSMutableDictionary` in `applicationDidEnterBackground` of `AppDelegate.m` an to a `plist` file. Immediately after saving it, I try to check if the file exists and read it back, but the file is not found.

```
NSString *photoCacheFilename = @"photoCache.plist";
[photoDict writeToFile:photoCacheFilename atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"File name: %@", photoCacheFilename);
BOOL isFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:photoCacheFilename];
if(isFile)
{
    NSLog (@"File found");
    NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:photoCacheFilename];
}
else
{
    NSLog (@"File not found");
}
```

I modified the code as suggested by some users, but still the file is not found. I am not sure if I am checking for the existence of file correctly.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *photoCacheFilename = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photoCache.plist"];

[photoDict writeToFile:photoCacheFilename atomically:YES];

BOOL isFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:photoCacheFilename];
if(isFile)
{
    NSLog (@"File found");
    NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:photoCacheFilename];
}
else
{
    NSLog (@"File not found");
}
```

Comment: photoCacheFilename should be complate path not just file name..

Comment: I tried the full path, as below, but still the same result: NSString *photoCacheFilename = [@"~/Documents/photoCache.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

Comment: get full path as he is doing in the answer of this [question][1].
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433598/write-into-plist-file-using-nsdictionary-object

Comment: see my edits in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specifying the correct path of the `Documents` directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *photoCacheFilename = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photoCache.plist"]; // Correct path to Documents Dir in the App Sand box

[photoDict writeToFile:photoCacheFilename atomically:YES]; //Write
```

Comment: hmm, can u check if `writeToFile` returns `true` or `false`?

Comment: `writeToFile` was failing. It looks like the dictionary I am trying to write contains data types that are not allowed to be written to a plist file. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a complete path to save data :

```
NSString *myFile = @"myFile.plist";
NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [filePaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myFile];
[photoDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: appears correct for me... try to instantiate your mutable dictionary without checking the existence of your file, put a breakpoint and check its value in your debug area

Comment: `writeToFile` was failing. It looks like the dictionary I am trying to write contains data types that are not allowed to be written to a plist file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What kind of datas are in your dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

***IN SWIFT 3.0***

***To get photoCache.plist file path which is in the document directory.***

```
func getPath() -> String {
        let plistFileName = "photoCache.plist"
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentPath = paths[0] as NSString
        let plistPath = documentPath.appendingPathComponent(plistFileName)
        return plistPath
    }
```

***To check whether the file exists or not.***

```
let plistPath = self.getPath()
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: plistPath) {
   //File Exists
}
```