# Sharing NSUserDefaults plist file?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I'd like to use the features of NSUserDefaults for saving state.  I do currently have that working.  But I want to copy this plist file and apply it to the same app on another device.

Is there some way to pass a file name to NSUserDefaults or do I need to use some other class?  Or is it fine to share the plist with the same app another device?

The app on device1 and device2 is the same app.  I'm not trying to share data between different apps.

Answer (score 1):

Would passing it as a dictionary work for you?

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
```

Then on the other device:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
for (NSString *key in dictionaryRepresentation.allKeys) {
    id ob = dictionaryRepresentation[key];
    [defaults setObject:ob forKey:key];
}
```

Or, you could write the `dict` to a `.plist` file, transport that over, decode from `.plist` to `dict` and do as I have above.

Writing to a `.plist` file:

```
[dict writeToFile:@"path/to/your/file.plist" atomically:YES];
```

Reading from a `.plist` file:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/your/file.plist"];
```

Comment: Seems like more work.  What's the advantage of this over app groups?

Comment: App groups imply the same device to me, but it sounded like you wanted to transmit data to a secondary device.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding app groups.  If you can share an app group across devices, by all means do so because that would likely be easier.

Comment: I'm not sure if app groups allow that.  I was just going off gregheo's answer.  I can't really find any info on app groups.  Your solution seems to solve getting the data serialized.  But how is it passed to device2?

Comment: For that part, I assumed you had some type of backend involved, going directly from app to app would involve multipeer connectivity or some sort of bluetooth connection.  If you're not doing a backend, I'd recommend multipeer.  You'll have to deal with permissions and stuff though, so perhaps a backend would be easier.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use icloud?

Comment: Oh yea, that would probably work fine! I just don't have experience with it, so I tend to overlook it.

Comment: Ok.  By the way, is there any reason you used a dictionary and not an array?

Comment: Yup, userDefaults is a key value store so it translates better to a dictionary.

Comment: hmmm, I'm currently using NSUserDefaults with an array to keep state.  I should probably be able to keep doing that right?  No reason to translate it into a dictionary.  I also call synchronize() to write the file.  How will the custom path work with that?  Also, writeToFile is not available.

Comment: No, what you're doing is fine, but userDefaults is basically just a dictionary that also has writing built in.  The custom path is used to go into your documents directory.  `writeToFile: atomically:` exists on `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. You can find info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191697/reading-and-writing-nsmutabledictionary-to-a-plist-file

Answer (score 0):

If they're both your apps, you could look into using [app groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) to have both apps access a shared container. You'd use NSUserDefaults as usual in this scenario.

Otherwise, you can't pass in a file name or URL to NSUserDefaults. You'd need to either roll your own with NSDictionary + archiving, or just do that one time – i.e. copy the current defaults to a plist, transfer that over somehow, and then write the values to the defaults.

Comment: Is there more info on app groups?  Searching the docs didn't turn up anything.  If device1 adds something to the plist and the app is running on device2, how does it handle the update since the app is open?  Also, does this use iCloud to move info from device to device?

Comment: Ah, I see the edit to the question that it's the same app on two devices. If it's the same user on both devices, iCloud key/value store would be one solution to keep them in sync if sync is what you want. App groups are more for multiple apps on the same device.